Cluster detection error (Invalid date in population file ) using rsatscan library purly spatial and discrete Poisson
I'm trying to run a purely spatial analysis using SaTScan in R, but I'm getting date-related errors even though I'm not using any temporal data. Here's the error:
Error: Invalid date '775' in population file, record 68.
Error: Invalid date '697' in population file, record 69.
I have 70 records and I have receieved this error for most of the records not all of them.
Here's my code:
    ss.options(list(
  # Input Files
  CaseFile=file.path(results_dir, "SS_Analysis.cas"),
  PopulationFile=file.path(results_dir, "SS_Analysis.pop"),
  CoordinatesFile=file.path(results_dir, "SS_Analysis.geo"),
  
  # Time Settings
 # StartDate="2018/01/01",
 # EndDate="2018/12/31",
  PrecisionCaseTimes=0,
  TimeAggregationUnits = 1, 
  
  # Analysis Settings
  CoordinatesType=1,  # 1 for latitude/longitude
  #AnalysisType = 1, #Purely Spatial
  ModelType=0,        # 1 for discrete Poisson
  ScanAreas=1 ,     # 1 for high rates
  ReportGiniClusters="n",
  MaxSpatialSizeInPopulationAtRisk="30",
  MonteCarloReps=999
))


My data structure:

case_file contains: location.id, count
pop_file contains: location.id, population
coord_file contains: location.id, latitude, longitude

I only want to perform spatial (not temporal) analysis. What am I missing?
